# How to create/signup different User types

Tags: python, django, django-models, one-to-one

I am trying to create two Users; Customers and Restaurants. I used the OneToOneField to relate these to the Django User model. I am confused on how I should go about creating the specific type of user. When I create the user how do I differentiate between which is a Customer and which is a Restaurant? This is what I have thus far, it seems to work but dont feel it is very elegant..

models.py

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    restaurant_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    restaurant_name = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=500)


class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

views.py

```
def signup_customer(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            last_name = request.POST['last_name']
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            email = request.POST['email']

            #TO DO CHECK IF IT ALREADY EXISTS

            user1 = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password,
                                            email=email)
            user1.save()
            user = Customer(customer_user=user1)

            login(request, user1)
        return redirect('dashboard')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to access the different relations from the User object by going:

```
user = User.objects.first()
user.restaurant
user.customer
```

So, to do what it sounds like you want to do(assign specific types to each User account), you'll have to check if they have a `restaurant` or `customer` related to their account.

What I would recommend doing is create a separate user profile table that stores additional information specific to the user that is similar between Customer and Restaurants and have a flag that you can check on there.

Comment: right, but is this the right way to go about saving different types of users?

Comment: There's nothing explicitly wrong with it. It's fine as it is, though there are better ways to do that. But that involves reading the documentation. Though it appears you're not using any of that additional info you're extracting from `request.POST`.

Comment: What you could do is create a post_save signal. I'll provide an example of that in my answer in just a minute.

Comment: I have seen the separate UserProfile class created, but did not really see the point of having an intermediate table, why not just relate straight to the Django User model?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. I was just saying so you could check the flag if the user is a Customer or Restaurant user. Without needing to check both fields. It would be slightly simpler in that you could do `user.userprofile.user_type`. As opposed to `if user.customer:' and `if user.restaurant` or whatever. It all boils down to the same thing, though. The only difference is that you wouldn't have redundant columns in your database with the additional UserProfile table.

Comment: ahhh i see what you mean, have not got that far to see that benefit yet. Ok thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this use case by **Django Groups**:

> Create two groups as Customer and Restaurant in ***shell_plus*** or ***management command*** or ***Django admin***

```
Group.objects.create(name="Customer")
Group.objects.create(name="Restaurant")
```

> Create two different models for Customer and Restaurant with user field relation as **One to One Mapping**.

```
# models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    """
    Customer Schema
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # add below customer attributes 

    def __str__(self):
       return self.user.first_name


class Restaruant(models.Model):
    """
    Restaruant Schema
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # add below restaruant attributes

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name
```

> Hold the group objects of Customer and Restaurant in constants file

```
# utils.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

RESTARUANT_GROUP = Group.objects.get(name="Restaruant")
CLIENT_GROUP = Group.objects.get(name="Client")
```

> While creating a user object, **add the user to the requested group (RESTARUANT_GROUP, CLIENT_GROUP)** and save the user object.

```
#views.py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from utils import RESTARUANT_GROUP, CLIENT_GROUP

def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user_type = request.POST.get('user_type') # user_type value would be client/restaruant
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=email,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        if user_type == "Restaruant":
            user.groups.add(RESTARUANT_GROUP)
        else:
            user.groups.add(CLIENT_GROUP)

        user.save()
```

> While user login, check user is **authenticated or not** and redirect to the user page based on the **user's group**.

```
def login(request):
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=email, password=password) # user authentication
    user = User.objects.get(id=user.id)
    if RESTARUANT_GROUP in user.groups.all(): # check user belongs to RESTARUANT_GROUP
        login(request, user)
        # redirect to restaruant page
    elif CLIENT_GROUP in user.groups.all(): # check user belongs to CLIENT_GROUP
        login(request, user)
        # redirect to client page
    else:
        # redirect to home page
```